# Помогите войти в php Adminer

Tags: php, html5, openserver

Я полный новичок в этом, поэтому объясняйте как дурачку. Мне нужно начать работать с базами данных и я по совету установил open server. Но когда я пытаюсь зайти в php Adminer какая-то белиберда:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неправильный пароль

Comment: это понятно, а какой надо?

Comment: откуда я знаю, ты же устанавливал ПО